# keyboard layout switching - non-working hotkeys in cyrillic layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I've got a small script that runs in background and handles setxkbmap for me. Said script has some logic of switching keyboard layouts, which is essential and is not supported by my DE installation (KDE).

Said script per-hotkey runs its handler logic and runs command:

```
$setxkbmap -layout <layout_name>
```

I've got problem with it: if I do

```
$setxkbmap -layout ru
```

Hotkeys in any application break, even the basic ones (Ctrl-C in terminal). What can be a reason for it? How can I solve said sad problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution instantly:

```
$setxkbmap -layout ru,us
```

allows me to use hotkeys in my terminal and whereever.